# How do you show that the estimator for the covariance matrix is unbiased?

Tags: proof-writing, covariance, parameter-estimation

So according to Wikipedia ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#Estimation_in_a_general_context))
the sample covariance matrix is an unbiased estimator of the covariance matrix, but how do I prove this mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

The proof can be found in the book by T.W. Anderson "An Introduction to Multivariate Statistical Analysis" 3ed,page 77.